# SwiperJS - show spinner between the images while loading

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, swiper.js

I am using SwiperJS for some galleries in my custom build Wordpress website. I am also using a plugin for lazy loading all my images, so the SwiperJS' own lazy load is disabled. However, now when the images are swiped and loading, there isn't any spinner to indicate that something is happening. Question is, how can I add this spinner with javascript myself.

Lets say now there is this rendered in the DOM:

```
       <div class="swiper-container">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                           
                        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="1" role="group" aria-label="3 / 7" style="width: 624px;">
                            <img src="path/to/src.jog" alt="" class="lazyloaded" data-ll-status="loaded">
                        </div>

                        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="2" role="group" aria-label="4 / 7" style="width: 624px;">
                            <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%20viewBox='0%200%200%200'%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="" data-lazy-src="//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/K0924-900x1200.jpg">
                        </div>

             </div>
      </div>
```

Slide, that is currently showing has the class `class="swiper-slide-active"` and the next one has `class="swiper-slide-next"`

When I swipe (or press the next arrow), the class `class="swiper-slide-next"` changes to `class="swiper-slide-active"` and its child, img tag receives the class `class="lazyloading"` and `data-ll-status="loading"`

After the image is loaded it changes to  `class="lazyloaded" data-ll-status="loaded"`

Now, how can I track with javascript the moment, when the img tag inside the div with the class `class="swiper-slide-active"` receives the class `class="lazyloading"` or `data-ll-status="loading"`, when that happens render inside `<div class="swiper-wrapper"> </div>` a spinner and when the `class="lazyloading"` changes to  `class="lazyloaded"` remove the spinner?

I would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that i understood your problem right :
You need to get a spinner when the image is loading ?

Check on https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading for the "swiper-lazy-preloader".

It should look like this :

```
<div class="swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Lazy image -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img data-src="path/to/picture-1.jpg" class="swiper-lazy" />
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#lazy-loading from v. 9 it uses browser loading="lazy" so it doesn't have its own API anymore, data-src needs to be src instead. The problem is it lazy loads all images/slides at once, not when sliding to the next slide one by one.